# Return original value, python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this selection of code:

```
def obsfucate_letters(letters):

    letters[0] = obsfucate_function()
    letters[1] = obsfucate_function()
    letters[2] = obsfucate_function()
    letters[3] = obsfucate_function()

    return letters

def obsfucate_function():

    import random as r
    randomnumber = r.random() * 100
    if randomnumber <= 16:
        letters1 = "!"
        return letters1
    elif randomnumber > 16 and randomnumber <= 30:
        letters1 = "%"
        return letters1
    elif randomnumber > 30 and randomnumber <= 45:
        letters1 = "&"
        return letters1
    elif randomnumber > 45 and randomnumber <= 60:
        letters1 = "*"
        return letters1
    elif randomnumber > 60 and randomnumber <= 75:
        letters1 = "#"
        return letters1
    elif randomnumber > 75 and randomnumber <= 90:
        letters1 = "@"
        return letters1
```

Now at the moment if the value random number is more than 90 it will just automatically give the value `None` and replace for example `letters[0]` with `None`.

But what I wanted it to do is that if the number is in between 90 and 100 I want it do display the original value. So whatever was stored in `letters[0]` originally.

Really not sure how to go about doing this. Hope I've explained it clearly enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could raise an exception instead, then by catching that exception prevent `letters[0]` to be replaced:

```
def obsfucate_letters(letters):
    try:    
        letters[0] = obsfucate_function()
    except ValueError:
        # ignore the exception, letters[0] will be unchanged
        pass

    try:
        letters[1] = obsfucate_function()
    except ValueError:
        pass

    try:
        letters[2] = obsfucate_function()
    except ValueError:
        pass

    try:
        letters[3] = obsfucate_function()
    except ValueError:
        pass

    return letters

def obsfucate_function():
    import random as r
    randomnumber = r.random() * 100
    if randomnumber <= 16:
        letters1 = "!"
        return letters1
    elif randomnumber > 16 and randomnumber <= 30:
        letters1 = "%"
        return letters1
    elif randomnumber > 30 and randomnumber <= 45:
        letters1 = "&"
        return letters1
    elif randomnumber > 45 and randomnumber <= 60:
        letters1 = "*"
        return letters1
    elif randomnumber > 60 and randomnumber <= 75:
        letters1 = "#"
        return letters1
    elif randomnumber > 75 and randomnumber <= 90:
        letters1 = "@"
        return letters1
    else:
        raise ValueError('random number out of range')
```

You could also *pass the current value* to the `obfuscate_function()` function, to be returned if the random value is greater than 90:

```
def obsfucate_letters(letters):
    letters[0] = obsfucate_function(letters[0])
    letters[1] = obsfucate_function(letters[1])
    letters[2] = obsfucate_function(letters[2])
    letters[3] = obsfucate_function(letters[3])

    return letters

def obsfucate_function(default):
    import random as r
    randomnumber = r.random() * 100
    if randomnumber <= 16:
        letters1 = "!"
        return letters1
    elif randomnumber > 16 and randomnumber <= 30:
        letters1 = "%"
        return letters1
    elif randomnumber > 30 and randomnumber <= 45:
        letters1 = "&"
        return letters1
    elif randomnumber > 45 and randomnumber <= 60:
        letters1 = "*"
        return letters1
    elif randomnumber > 60 and randomnumber <= 75:
        letters1 = "#"
        return letters1
    elif randomnumber > 75 and randomnumber <= 90:
        letters1 = "@"
        return letters1
    else:
        return default
```

You could try and avoid repeating yourself as much; use a loop in `obfuscate_letters` for example:

```
def obsfucate_letters(letters):
    for i in range(len(letters)):
        try:
            letters[i] = obfuscate_function()
        except ValueError:
            # don't replace a letter when the random value was out of range
            pass

    return letters
```

or passing in a the current value:

```
def obsfucate_letters(letters):
    for i in range(len(letters)):
        letters[i] = obfuscate_function(letters[i])

    return letters
```

Your `obsfucate_function()` could be simplified too; either by just using `random.choice()` for the character choices and a separate 10% chance no change is made, or by using `bisect` to pick a character or the default based on cumulative weightings.

Using `random.choice()`:

```
import random

def obsfucate_function(default):
    if random.random() < 0.1:
        # 10% chance the default is picked
        return default
    return random.choice('!%&*#@')
```

Using bisection:

```
import random
import bisect

def obsfucate_function(default):
    cumulative_weights = [16, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 100]
    values = ['!', '%', '&', '*', '#', '@', default]
    return values[bisect.bisect(cumulative_weights, random.randrange(100))]
```

The `random.choice()` option does not exactly replicate your original function, as the chance to pick a `!` is 16%, while the rest of the characters have a 15% chance of being picked. The bisection approach will pick characters with the exact same probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

It's returning none because your value isn't returning a value. Our in other words, you didn't define a final elif condition for the range between 90 and 100

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use `letters[i] = obsfucate_function() or letters[i]`. When obsfucate_function returns None (randomnumber > 90), it will automatically use the value of letters[i].

BTW, you probably wanted to use obfuscate and not obsfucate.